# Optimality conditions in convex programming

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm reading about Zero-order conditions in Nonlinear Programming and the following confuses me (my questions are below the theory):

[image]

> Consider the set $\Gamma \subset E^{n+1} = \{(r,\textbf{x}): r\geq f(\textbf{x}), \textbf{x}\in E^n\}.$ In a figure of the graph of $f$,
>   the set $\Gamma$ is the region above the graph, shown in the upper
>   part of the figure. This set is called the *epigraph* of $f$. It is
>   easy to verify that the set $\Gamma$ is convex if $f$ is convex
>   function. Suppose that $\textbf{x}^*\in \Omega$ is the minimizing
>   point with value $f^*= f(\textbf{x}^*).$ We construct a tubular region
>   with cross section $\Omega$ and extending vectically from $-\infty$ up
>   to $f^*$, shown as $B$ in the upper part of the figure. This is also a
>   convex set, and it overlaps the set $\Gamma$ only at the boundary
>   point $(f^*, \textbf{b}^*)$ above $\textbf{x}^*$ (or possibly many
>   boundary points if $f$ is flat near $\textbf{x}^*$).
>
> According to the separating hyperplane theorem, there is a hyperplane
>   separating these two sets. This hyperplane can be represented by a
>   nonzero vector of the form $(s,\boldsymbol \lambda)\in E^{n+1}$ with
>   $s$ a scalar and $\boldsymbol \lambda\in E^n$, and a separation
>   constant $c$. The separation conditions are
>
> $$sr + \boldsymbol \lambda^T\textbf{x} \geq c\;\;\;\text{for all $\textbf{x} \in E^n$ and $r\geq f(\textbf{x})$}\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$  $$sr + \boldsymbol \lambda^T\textbf{x} \leq c\;\;\;\text{for all $\textbf{x}
>  \in \Omega$ and $r\leq f^*$}.\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$
>
> It follows that $s\neq0$; for otherwise $\boldsymbol \lambda \neq\textbf{0}$ and then (1) would be violated for some $\textbf{x}\in E^n$. It also follows that $s\geq0$ since otherwise (2) would be
>   violated by very negative values of $r$. Hence, together we find $s>0$
>   and by appropriate scaling we may take $s=1$.

My questions are:

1) Why did $B$ overlap $\Gamma$ at the point $(f^*, \textbf{b}^*)$? I thought it should be $(f^*, \textbf{x}^*)$

2) Why is $s\neq0$ and $s\geq0$? I didn't understand this

3) Why may we take $s=1$?

Please let me know if you need more information, thank you for any help! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 1) is just a misprint. Indeed, it should read $(f^*, x^*)$.

Ad 2): Assume $s = 0$. Then, we have
$\lambda^\top \, x \ge c$ for all $x \in E^n$. This yields $\lambda = 0$ which contradicts $(s, \lambda) \ne 0$.

Now Assume $s < 0$. But then $s \, r + \lambda^\top \, x \le c$ is violated, since $r$ could be arbitrarily small.

This yields $s > 0$.

Ad 3): This is just a simple scaling argument.
Set $s^* = 1 = s/s$, $c^* = c / s$ and $\lambda^* = \lambda / s$ and divide
(1) and (2) by $s$.

By the way:
I am wondering why you called these conditions ``zero-order'' conditions.
Indeed, by evaluating (1) and (2), one should arrive at
$-\lambda \in \partial f(x^*)$ (the convex subdifferential of $f$ at $x^*$)
and
$\lambda \in N_\Omega(x^*)$ (the normal cone of $\Omega$ at $x^*$),
which is just the first order condition
$0 \in \partial f(x^*) + N_\Omega(x^*)$.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @gerw =) About your question, in my book this is the theory which precedes the definition for zero-order conditions. Right after this text it follows in my book that: "It is easy to see that the above conditions can be expressed alternatively as two optimization problems, as stated in the following proposition" and then follows zero-order necessary conditions :) Did that clarify? Do you think I should change the title of my question?

Comment: Can you give the title of the book? Maybe you could change the title to "optimality conditions in convex programming"?

Comment: Yes, the book is Linear and Nonlinear programming, third edition by David G. Luenberger. Page 199. Okay, I will change the title =)